# Visual Studio hangs on running more than 300 unit tests at once

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nunit, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am using Visual Studio 2013 ultimate and trying to analyze code coverage for one of my project DLL which has around 350 unit tests written under NUnit test framework. I have installed NUnit adapter which works fine till 250 unit tests and then hangs forever and never finishes the execution.

Is there any way to run test cases partially and get a cumulative code coverage report or any workaround for running all of the tests at once so VS don't hang again.

Comment: It seems very odd that VS would crash just running 300 unit tests. Do you experience any performance problems or high memory usage at 250 tests?

Comment: 350 is a very small number as tests go. If you give us more info, we can try to figure out what's happening and solve that problem. Then you won't need a coverage workaround at all.

Comment: Info needed: versions of everything you are using. Whether tests can be run successfully using other runners, such as the nunit console runner.

Comment: Creating the playlists for 100 UT each worked well. At the end all I need to do is merging the coverage results.